# List of supported video types across browsers

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Is there a comprehensive list of video codecs and their relative support amongst desktop and mobile browser platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/ Is probably the best source of HTML5/CSS3 etc compatability tables.

http://caniuse.com/#search=video shows compatability for the various video elements and codecs.

http://findmebyip.com/litmus is a popular alternative